# Firefox sets Content-Type of uploaded .xls file to "application/vdn.ms-excel". Is it a Browser bug?

Tags: firefox, file-upload, cross-browser, mime-types

Firefox 30 uploads EXCEL files as "application/vdn.ms-excel". All other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera) set the Content-Type to "application/vnd.ms-excel", which I think is correct. (Note the difference: "vdn" vs "vnd")

Is that a Firefox bug? From my understanding, only the browser controls which Content-Type is set.

Here is the relevant part from a POST request:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileUploadCostUnit"; filename="Kostenstellen.xls"
Content-Type: application/vdn.ms-excel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the MIME type is OS specific. I encountered the error on Ubuntu 12.04 but not on Arch Linux (both Firefox 30.0).

I conclude it is a bug. However, I'm not sure whether it is a Firefox bug or a bug in some OS specific library used by Firefox.

Comment: Have you recently installed any new packages? Try to find whether your databases are okay, e.g. using `grep -R vdn.ms-excel /usr/share/mime ~/.local/share/mime`. If you find and fix an occurrence and the bug is not fixed, try running `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime` (or `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`).

Comment: @RobW Thanks, that is a good idea. Currently, I have no access to the machine but I will check it.

Comment: @RobW Both /usr/share/mime and ~/.local/share/mime are correct. They contain only the correct "application/vnd.ms-excel". However, Firefox still sends "vdn". So, Firefox seems to use another heuristic to determine the MIME types.